# How can I set an Apex trigger for leads for the first time an activity is logged on that lead by a particular user or set of users?

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

This is part of a larger project to calculate each Lead's "time to first touch", i.e. how long it takes us to personally call or email a lead.  This is complicated by the fact that activities are also logged by Marketo (almost always moments after the lead is created), so I need to only trigger when it's a human user logging the activity.

So I have a custom field, `Response_time__c`, which I want to set to `Now() - CreatedDate` the first time a human rep logs an activity.

How would I build this trigger?

Comment: What user does Marketo create the activities as? Is it the user that created the lead, or a dedicated system user? Are you otherwise able to distinguish the records that were created by Marketo?

Comment: Yes, Marketo has its own seat (alias = "Marketo").  Aside from excluding activities logged by Marketo, I may also want to be able to isolate activities logged by people in specific roles, i.e. actual sales reps as opposed to managers/operations/customer support etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the details you identified, *Marketo has its own seat (alias = "Marketo")*, to detect the correct scenario in the trigger.

```
// Could equally use getUserName() or getName(). 
// Custom Hierarchy setting check will give you more flexibility between orgs and for bulk data loading to bypass the trigger.
if(UserInfo.getUserId() == SomeCustomSetting.MarketoUserId) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'SomeTriggerName bypassing for Marketo');
    return;
}

if(UserInfo.getUserRoleId() == SomeCustomSetting.IsolateSpecificRole) {
    // Do something specific in the trigger based on the users role
}
```

See also:

- [UserInfo](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) - Contains methods for obtaining information about the context user.

As a rough trigger:

```
trigger LeadResponseTrigger on Task (after insert) {
    if(UserInfo.getUserId() == SomeCustomSetting.MarketoUserId) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'LeadResponseTrigger bypassing for Marketo');
       return;
    }

    Set<Id> leadsToCheck = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.WhoId != null && String.valueOf(t.WhoId).startsWith('00Q')) {
            leadsToCheck.add(t.WhoId);
        }
    }

    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = [Select Id, CreatedDate 
                                From Lead 
                                where ID in :leadsToCheck and Response_time__c = null];
    for(Lead l : leadsToUpdate) {
        l.Response_time__c = Date.Today() - l.CreatedDate;
    }
    update leadsToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat helpful.  I realized that my main confusion was in the fact that I have to have the trigger be the creation of a new Task, rather than an update of the related Lead.  If info on the User passes the above tests, I need to look at the related Lead and somehow determine if this is the _first_ Activity created by a valid user.  Once I know that, I can edit the field in question on the Lead.

So my issue is, how do I figure out that the activity is the _first_ one related to the Lead that passes the User test above?

Comment: @Oren In theory the Activity will be the first one to be inserted where the user isn't Marketo and the field is currently null. I've added a very rough trigger to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is super helpful.  Based on [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005091&language=en_US) it seems that if I want Response_time_c to be a number of minutes, I would put in
`( Now() - CreatedDate ) * 1440`

Comment: @Oren Yes, there are 1440 minutes in a day (24 * 60). So multiplying the decimal days by 1440 will give you the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Daniel Ballinger for the assistance.  Here is the trigger I finally wrote:

```
trigger LeadResponseTrigger on Task (before insert, before update) {
    if( UserInfo.getUserId() == '<Marketo's User ID>' ) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'LeadResponseTrigger bypassing for Marketo');
       return;
    }

    Set<Id> leadsToCheck = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.WhoId != null && String.valueOf(t.WhoId).startsWith('00Q') && t.Status != 'Pending' && t.ActivityDate <= Date.Today()) {
            leadsToCheck.add(t.WhoId);
        }
    }

    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = [Select Id, CreatedDate 
                                From Lead 
                                where ID in :leadsToCheck and First_touch_time__c = null AND CreatedDate > 2014-12-17T12:00:00Z ];
    for(Lead l : leadsToUpdate) {

        l.First_touch_time__c = System.now();
    }
    update leadsToUpdate;

}
```

So it timestamps the event on the Lead field `First_touch_time__c`, and I created a second regular formula field called "Minutes to First Touch": `(First_touch_time__c - CreatedDate) * 1440`.  Works like a charm :-)